# General definition of orientation-preserving (continuous) map of surfaces

Tags: general-topology, orientation, mapping-class-group

Everybody seems to just use these maps but there is never a formal definition given. I looked at this question: [Orientation preserving homeomorphisms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1737739/orientation-preserving-homeomorphisms)
but no answer is given and I can't make sense of the comments.

I've never seen a formal definition of orientability either, our professor just drew a circle-arrow on the blackboard. So I'm going with the definition I found on Wikipedia at the moment: A surface has an orientation if there is a triangulation such that I can draw a circle-arrow on each triangle such that on neighboring triangles the arrows on the circle 'point in the same direction', i.e. I could continuously move one into the other.
Now going from this rather intuitive intuition, what does it mean for a self-homeomorphism to be orientation-preserving? I would suspect it means something like, if I describe my circle-arrow as embeddings $\gamma:S^1\rightarrow X$ which 'grow in the same direction as the arrow on the circle points' and where X is my space, then if the image $\phi\circ\gamma$ lies in some triangle, it again 'grows in the same direction' as the arrow on the circle in that triangle points. Is this correct?

Comment: If these are smooth surfaces, the best (IMO) definition is in terms of the derivative and its determinant.

Comment: Can you give me a reference?

Comment: Guillemin and Pollack's "Differential Topology" is pretty readable.  Maybe someone can give a surface-oriented source (no pun intended).

Comment: What's your definition of surface?

Comment: A Hausdorff--space which is locally homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$. But I have only dealt with closed manifolds up until now, so maybe something about second-countability as well if I'm dropping the closedness. Basically I am only looking at the punctured disk in the complex plane and its universal cover.

Comment: OK. When you work with smooth maps it's a lot easier because you can talk about derivatives; usually when people work with topological surfaces they define orientations with homology. There is a more down-to-earth approach that I'll write as an answer later today probably.

Comment: I'm studying Mapping Class Groups, and they are defined on the closed unit disk $\mathbb{D}\subset\mathbb{C}$. I think that since each of the elements in the mapping class group contains a diffeomorphism, I might as well assume that it's smooth or something like that since $\mathbb{D}$ is 'sufficiently nice'. I don't have much experience with this topic so I don't know if what I'm writing is correct.